# Exponentiation conversion

Tags: vba, precision, ms-project

I am using:

```
For t = 1 To ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
    With Tasks(t)
        ' DurSen is a Custom Field Name. It returns an application field Number (such as 188743770 for Number4)
        Projectfield = FieldNameToFieldConstant("DurSen")
        ' the SpearmanRankCorrelation function occasionally produces a result like -6.06060606060606E-03.
        .SetField (Projectfield), SpearmanRankCorrelation(ProjectDuration, TmpVec, NN)
    End With
Next t
```

This is a number expressed as an exponent. Due to the presence of the `"E"` in the number, it fails the `Setfield` function. The `.Setfield`  places the calculated value into the field referenced by ProjectField for a specific task, (t) but fails when the calculated value contains an "E".

Any ideas on avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [SetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.setfield) method expects the Value parameter to be a string. So the solution is to format the number as a string. (e.g. `Format(-6.06060606060606E-03, "0.0#####") => -0.006061`)

**However, Microsoft Project will round the value to the nearest hundredth, so you will lose the precision.**

Better to store numbers that require more than two decimal places in a text field and convert them back to numbers as needed in code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simpler answer hat I figured out yesterday. Instead of trying to deal with it as a number, I simply converted to a string, used the InStr method to see if an "E" was present and if it is, assign a value of 0.001 as the result, as any E value will be smaller than .01.

If InStr(SpearmanRankCorrelation(ProjectDuration, TmpVec, NN), "E") > 0 Then
                            .SetField (Dursen), 0.001
                            PD = 0.001
                            outputstr = ("575 - ID= " & tasks(t).ID & " SpearmanRankCorrelation= " & SpearmanRankCorrelation(ProjectDuration, TmpVec, NN) & " Replaced by 0.001")
                            Call Txt_Append(myfile, outputstr)
                          Else
                            .SetField (Dursen), SpearmanRankCorrelation(ProjectDuration, TmpVec, NN)
                       End If

Thank you, Rachel, for your answer.  I am trying not to use Project Custom fields.  The .Setfield above assigns the Result to the field which is identified by the value of Dursen ( which is an internal field reference).

Answer (score 0):

Rachel,  I tried your approach but whenever I encountered a result that was expressed with an "E" in the Result, the conversion failed.  using >Setfield will only round to the nearest hundreth if the entire string is a numeric value (when converted).  The >Setfield method does not work when there is an "E" in the expression.